# Folder names - replace the Full Stop with a Space

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with subfolder names similar to this:

```
The.Train.To.Morning.Town
```

I would like to replace all the `.` with a space.

I have tried to use this

```
$dir = "k:\test"
CD $dir
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -match '.'} |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.',' '}
```

But I then get an error, where am I going wrong ? Thank you

> Rename-Item : The path is not of a legal form. At line:5 char:1 + Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.',' '}

Comment: If I'm not wrong the `-replace`operator works with regex where the dot "." stands for any charachter. If you're looking for a literal dot you will have to escape it with a backslash  `-replace '\.',' '`

Comment: This works thanks you, but also renames the "." for the file extension within the folder e.g. the folder The.Train.To.Morning.Town contains an AVI The.Train.To.Morning.Town.avi . Anyway to exclude the extension ?

Comment: `Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.replace('.',' ')+$_.Extension}`

Comment: In addition to the code from @Olaf - You can also use the Directory param if you don't want to rename files: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Recurse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Olaf got it correct in the comments, and should have submitted it as an answer. The PowerShell [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) operator takes a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6) as the search-for parameter; as the `.` is the regular expression for 'match any character', you need to "escape" it with a backslash `\`: `$_.Name -replace '\.',' '`

You indicate in the comments to the question that this was also removing the `.` for the file extension; it would have been a good idea to have included the information that you were concerned about the extension in the original question. With respect to that, however, @LotPings provided a good solution to handle that case (`{$_.BaseName.replace('.',' ')+$_.Extension}`) - note that the [`.Replace()` method](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) (Note: Link is to SS64; I can't find the Microsoft Docs page on this) does *not* use regular expressions, and thus the `.` does not need to be escaped.